# Calling a variable assigned to an object

Tags: excel, vba

This is a small portion of my code:

```
If cell1.Offset(0, 8) = "Alpha" Then
   Set cell_target = cell2
ElseIf cell1.Offset(0, 8) = "Bravo" Then
   Set cell_target = cell3
Else
   MsgBox "ERROR"
   End
End if
```

where cell1 is just a cell inside a for...next loop within `myRange` on Sheet1 and cell2 and cell3 are just single cells (range "A2") located on Sheet2 and Sheet3.

At the end of my code, I want to shift either cell2 or cell3 (depending on what `cell_target` is in the code above) down by one row, which I do in the following line of code:

```
If cell_target = cell2 Then
   Set cell2 = cell2.Offset(1)
ElseIf cell_target = cell3 Then
   Set cell3 = cell3.Offset(1)
Else
   MsgBox "ERROR"
   End
End if
```

The problem is that all of the cells are treated as cell2 even if they are not. I have worked around this problem by writing:

```
If cell1.Offset(0, 8) = "Alpha" Then
   Set cell2 = cell2.Offset(1)
ElseIf cell1.Offset(0, 8) = "Bravo" Then
   Set cell3 = cell3.Offset(1)
Else
   MsgBox "ERROR"
   End
End if
```

I am just curious why the first method did not work. My personal guess is that by typing `cell_target = cell2`, the code was not checking the reference name (cell2 or cell3) (which is what I need) but whether `cell2` is an object or not; and since it was, all the cells ended up being treated as cell2. 
I would greatly appreciate if you could either confirm my understanding or refute it and clarify this issue for me. Should my description be too vague, I could provide my code in full either here or via an Excel file.

Comment: Your test is only checking if the values are the same, not whether they are the same cells. You could test the `.Address` property or use: `If cell_target Is cell2 Then`

Comment: @Rory is right. Just exercise caution when comparing the `.Address` properties (esp. if the cells are on different sheets or workbooks) because `Sheet1.Range("A1").Address = Sheet2.Range("A1").Address` would return `True`.

Comment: Good point made by @Ambie - if you use the address make sure to use `.Address(External:=True)`

Comment: @Rory and @Ambie, thank you very much for your insightful comments! `Is` operator is exactly what I needed, @Rory! Should you wish to re-post your first comment as an answer, I will tick it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the earlier comments, your test is only checking if the **values** are the same, not whether they are the same cells.

You could test the `.Address(External:=True)` property or use:

```
If cell_target Is cell2 Then
```

Small note about the `Is` operator with ranges: it will work here because you assigned one range variable to the other directly. However if you had assigned say Range("A1") to two variables, the `Is` operator would return `False` when you compared them, because the Range property returns a new reference each time.

Comment: Thank you, @Rory, for that additional comment on the `Is` operator.

Answer (score 0):

As commented already, your test compares the cell contents.

I would suggest to check

`Interect(cell_target,cell2).Cells.Count>0`